# Copy-Item with timeout

Tags: powershell

I am recovering files from a hard drive wherein some number of the files are unreadable.   I'm unable to change the hardware level timeout / ERC, and it's extremely difficult to work around when I have several hundred thousand files, any tens of thousands of which might be unreadable.

The data issues were the result of a controller failure.  Buying a matching drive (all the way down), I've been able to access the drive, and can copy huge swaths of it without issues.  However, there are unreadable files dotted throughout the drive that, when accessed, will cause the SATA bus to hang. I've used various resumable file copy applications like `robocopy`, RichCopy, and a dozen others, but they all have the same issue.  They have a RETRY count that is based on actually getting an error reported from the drive. The issue is that the drive is taking an extremely long time to report the error, and this means that a single file may take up to an hour to fail officially.   I know how fast each file SHOULD be, so I'd like to build a powershell CMDLET or similar that will allow me to pass in a source and destination file name, and have it try to copy the file.  If, after 5 seconds, the file hasn't copied (or if it has - this can be a dumb process), I'd like it to quit. I'll write a script that fires off each copy process individually, waiting for the process before it to finish, but I'm so far unable to find a good way of putting a time limit on the process.

Any suggestions you might have would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I would be happy with spawning a `Copy-Item` in a new thread, with a new PID, then counting down, then killing that PID.  I'm just a novice at PowerShell, and have seen so many conflicting methods for imposing timers that I'm lost on what the best practices way would be.

**Edit 2:**  Please note that applications like `robocopy` will utterly hang when encountering the bad regions of the disk.  These are not simple hangs, but bus hangs that windows will try to preserve in order to not lose data.  In these instances task manager is unable to kill the process, but Process Explorer IS.  I'm not sure what the difference in methodology is, but regardless, it seems relevant.

Comment: [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) /w:10 /r:1

Comment: @lloyd That's going to retry once after timeout + 10 seconds.

Comment: Lloyd, In this instance, Robocopy is not receiving a message from the drive that the operation has failed, so the retry count ends up not mattering.  The drive will sit and happily pretend it's still fetching the data for many, many hours (per file), so it will never reasonably get to the retry counter.

Comment: Yes, replace the values with what you need and place it in a [try catch block](http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell) if needed. /mt will give you multiple threads.

Comment: Alright I'll propose a solution, but normally you should attempt to solve it yourself and show your code.

Comment: I've attempted to code this in several ways, but in each instance, I've been unable to find a way to terminate the child process.  Someone directed me to powershell as an option, but it's not a scripting language I've worked with in the past.  It appears that Try/Catch is pretty traditional in that it seems to expect an exception in order to catch.  There is no exception, so nothing to catch.  I suppose I could wrap the instantiation of the copy process in a block that will intentionally throw an exception after a few seconds, and FINALLY kill the PID that I spawned in code?

Comment: I have'nt seen any code, please update your question with your attempt in powershell or any other language and I can be more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the canonical way of doing things like this in PowerShell are [background jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
$timeout = 300 # seconds

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item ... }
Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout $timeout
Stop-Job -Job $job
Receive-Job -Job $job
Remove-Job -Job $job
```

Replace `Copy-Item` inside the scriptblock with whatever command you want to run. Beware though, that all variables you want to use inside the scriptblock must be either defined inside the scriptblock, passed in via the `-ArgumentList` parameter, or prefixed with the `using:` scope qualifier.

An alternative to `Wait-Job` would be a loop that waits until the job is completed or the timeout is reached:

```
$timeout = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(5)
do {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
} while ($job.State -eq 'Running' -and (Get-Date) -lt $timeout)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer!  As I suspected MIGHT be an issue given the issues with SATA when it hangs, the process isn't killed at the end, and can only be released by disconnecting the drive.  I tested it with a copy from a known working drive and it worked exactly as expected.   My next step is going to be to send a powerdown command to a microcontroller  in between files if the process isn't killed.   This code does appropriately take care of the timing, and I'm very grateful!  Thanks! edit: and thank you for the editing help!