# Limit of an individual PowerShell command

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I am running below script to get CPU utilization from multiple servers.However there are a couple of computers I have come across where the below script just sticks forever i.e. no error, no console output. So I have used Job command to kill after specific time period. But when am trying to execute this code am getting below error.

Is there a way to set a time limit of an individual PowerShell command?

```
$ServerList = ("xyz","abc")
foreach ($computername in $ServerList) {
    $timeout = 30
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $using:computername |
            Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average |
            Select Average
    }
    Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout $timeout
    Stop-Job -Job $job
    Receive-Job $job
    Remove-Job -Job $job
}
```

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or
empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command
again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy-Item with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623767/copy-item-with-timeout)

Comment: `Start-Job -Computer $computername -Scriptblock {Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | ...; ...} -Timeout ...`

Comment: Thanks for the Replay @Ansgar Wiechers                                      Below code not showing any output can you check once                                                                      $computername="XYZ"
$timeout = 300 
$job = Start-Job -computername $computername -Scriptblock { Get-WmiObject win32_processor |  Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average }
Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout $timeout
Stop-Job -Job $job
Receive-Job -Job $job
Remove-Job -Job $job

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. `Start-Job` doesn't have a parameter `-Computer`, so use this: `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject -Computer $using:computername Win32_Processor | ...}`.

Comment: Thanks, But still i have some problem with script. When i am declaring variable outside Script block, its not taking inside block. Is there any way to make Global variable?
$ServerList=("XYZ")
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
ForEach($computername in $ServerList)  
{ 
$timeout = 300 # seconds
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject -computername $computername win32_processor |  Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average } 
Wait-Job -Job $job -Timeout $timeout
Stop-Job -Job $job
Receive-Job -job $job
Remove-Job -Job $job
}

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment. You need `$using:computername` inside the scriptblock to be able to access the variable `$computername` outside the scriptblock. Also, please avoid posting code in comments, because it quickly becomes unreadable. Instead [edit] your question.

Comment: Thanks, Can you check once code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had missed that you're using PowerShell v2. The `using:` scope modifier isn't available prior to PowerShell v3, so you need to use the the `-ArgumentList` parameter for passing the computer name into the scriptblock.

Change this:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $using:computername |
        Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average |
        Select Average
}
```

into this:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $args[0] |
        Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average |
        Select -Expand Average
} -ArgumentList $computername
```